# Simple file cache - how to handle expiry

Tags: php, caching

I have a requirement for a super basic file based cache storage.  It will store chunks of text data for variable lengths of time.

I don’t need anything fancy but simply a way to store data, retrieve data and to invalidate it.

I have a method to invalidate on command.  so that is covered.

I want to now allow automatic invalidation after a set time-out.

My current strategy to achieve this is to create a future Unix time-stamp and append that to the cache file name.  When the cache file is being requested, the appended date can be checked with the current time-stamp to determine whether it is still valid.

The will work, but it means parsing the file name to determine the cache status.

Any alternatives?

Comment: You could put the expire time in the file itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [filemtime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php) function to check if the cache is still fresh or not. It's pretty fast and you wouldn't have to bother with parsing filenames.

```
$now = time();
$expires = 15 * 60;
$modified = filemtime('/tmp/cache');

$isFresh = ($expires + $modified) < $now;
```